# Set permissions on file generated by Stored Procedure

Tags: java, database, unix, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure which is generating a file with some Data in tables on our Unix server.
I want the stored procedure to also set Read/Write permission on that file to group and everyone.
How can I do that. Please help.

Comment: please specify what database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

See: `http://jenniferlinca.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/using-utl_file-how-file-permissions-are-determined-working-sample/`

Short answer, the user (usually oracle) has a umask.  That is passed on to the utl_file.fopen procedure.  If the java process opens the file and then reads data from a cursor:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set%29

which for is java 7: setPosixFilePermissions